# Where do confiscated items go?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

After getting caught stealing a few things in skyrim, I noticed that most of the stolen items got confiscated. However, when I went back to the original place of the item, it was gone.

So my question is, does the confiscated items get stored somewhere specific, or are there no way of getting them back?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When they're confiscated, they're placed in an evidence chest. These chests can be found in the jails themselves and in guard houses.

If you have the chutzpah, you can re-enter the jail once you serve your time and seek it out. It's usually around the same area as the belongings chest: the location is different depending on the jail, but checking the barracks or the entrances (or even sometimes right next to your cell) are generally a good bet.

Comment: Do they stay in the evidence chest forever?

Comment: @mordi2k That I don't know. Since you can try and get them after you serve your time, it seems that it's certainly possible they stay there forever. I'd have to do some testing over the weekend to confirm that.

Comment: My guess, based on previous TES games, would be that the items either stay there forever or are overwritten by your next haul when you get pinched again.

Comment: they are overwritten, i got caught, escaped, got caught again without getting stuff back, came back and nothing...

Answer (score 5):

It goes into the evidence chest of the jail/dungeon where you where arrested.