# How can I get back an item that was confiscated when I was arrested?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where do confiscated items go?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35122/where-do-confiscated-items-go)

I found Calixto's Journal (which I assume is related to the Blood on Ice quest in Windhelm) early on in my looting and then forgot about it. Later on, I was arrested in Solitude, and had all my stolen items confiscated from me.

Now, I have begun the Blood on Ice quest, and it seems that the journal has become important. Is there anywhere that confiscated items are stored, or are they simply removed from existence?

Comment: I tried searching but sometimes you just miss it. Voted to close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, there is in each prison a locked chest called "confiscated item chest". When you get arrested, every stolen items you have get put in this chest. I don't know if it reseted after a while, but if not, the journal. I also contain all your equipment when you get send into prison.

I know that the one in solitude can be accessed trough a secret passageway behind the cell you are in, although I've never seen the "official" side of the prison.