# Where do confiscated items go in Markarth?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I was in Markarth, and got my stolen items taken. I checked the Guard's Tower and the Keep, but I couldn't find anything. Any clues as to where my items are?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where do confiscated items go?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35122/where-do-confiscated-items-go)

Answer (score 3):

"Enter Cidhna Mine and you will have to pickpocket a key to the mine off of one of the silver-blood guards. once you have the key, there are tunnels and one leads to a cell door, on the other side is a room. unlock the door with the key and enter the two chests inside, that's where the evidence and prisoner belongings are held. It took me a while to find the Markarth evidence chest." [Source.](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/xbox360/615803-the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim/answers/306570-evidence-chest)

Note that if you are arrested again, the items in the chest will disappear.